# Is there an easier way to solve this system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals, symmetric-functions

$xy=26$

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=8$

Instead of solving for $x$ or $y$ in one of the equations and then plugging it in into the other, I want to find a faster, more efficient way to solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Perhaps you could start by $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2=64+2\cdot26=64+52=116$. It is not clear from your statement what would qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

S.B.S

$x^2$+$y^2=64$

$(x+y)^2 - 2xy = 64$

or

$(x-y)^2 + 2xy = 64$

then after that you can do it..

Comment: If you put the dollar signs at the end of the line it looks nicer